# How to correctly bundle 3rd-party-libraries into library projects for .jar creation?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, loopj

I'm trying to build an SDK **library** (.jar) that developers can include in their projects. The **library** project will use the loopj network 3rd party library to achieve network functionality. ***So, I need to bundle a library (loopj) into another library (our custom library), and output a jar.***

There are two projects, (1) the **SDK library project**, and (2) the **demo android application project** used to test the SDK library.

The SDK library project compiles fine, and the classes using loopj classes are able to reference them without issue. I compile the SDK project to output a .jar file to test in the demo android project.

The problem is, when I add the .jar file to the demo application project, there is an error that the library classes cannot 'see' loopj network classes (error at bottom). Strange, because the relevant classes had no problem seeing loopj back in the library project.. So, I assume I did not add the loopj library correctly into the library project. Perhaps I missed a step somewhere..

**Things I Tried:**

- Added loopj jar to library project (SDK) via *'File > Project Structure > Libraries > + Add'*
- Confirmed that loopj classes visible to library project (SDK)
- Exported the library project (SDK) itself, as a jar
- Added the SDK's jar to the demo application project, to test
- *(demo project crashes: loopj classes not found by SDK object)*

**Question:** *what's the process to correctly bundle 3rd party libraries into library projects for .jar creation?*

*Using Intellij IDEA 14 CE

```
02-20 12:44:43.535  20301-20301/com.zoids.android.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zoids.android.example, PID: 20301
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient
            at com.zoids.Zoids.detectImageWithURL(Zoids.java:184)
            at com.zoids.android.example.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all this problem is due to missing jar on your classpath/build path
So try to right click your project and add external jars like loopj and add it to the path of your project ...

Secondly to bundle all of them together....there is usually an option to export the project ...Choose jar as an output and that's it.hope it helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the step of adding jars? I added mine by going to File > Project Structure > Libraries > + Add Library (My IDE is Intellij IDEA 14) but if this is not the right way let me know.

Comment: When you right click on the jar , do you see the option add to build path ?